# PHP script execution time of 2 weeks possible?

Tags: php

I have created a PHP script which scrapes 1 mio. domains and analyzes the content. I tested it locally and it takes 20 mins per 1,000 domains scraped.

Can I just setup a server with it and let it run for 2 weeks or is there a reason why a PHP file would crash after a certain execution time?

Comment: On the command line this would be fine. Assuming you don't have a memory leak. Though running for each domain would likely be better for starting part way through if you need to

Comment: He never implied that he didn't run this script simply for each domain.  He just said he can do 1000 domains per 20 minutes, roughly.  Still wouldn't really do much except prevent memory overflows which you can still set to be infinity if you set your php.ini.  So there wouldn't really be an issue, just have to make sure that you have a way to initialize the script from a specific point because if it crashes in the middle of the script and you scraped 50,000 sites, you want to easily be able to start on #50,001.

Answer (score 2):

If you run PHP from the console, it has no max execution time. That being said, you should probably rearchitect your idea if it takes 2 weeks to execute. Maybe have a js frontend that calls a PHP script that scrapes 5 or 10 domains at a time...

Comment: Why would he want to wrap this simple script with a front-end?  He just needs to make sure that the script can be started from a specific point so that it can resume from where it left off in case it crashes.  This is just a simple script to scrape some websites and doing 5 at once versus doing 1 per iteration arguably wouldn't have an affect on how long it would take to finish.

Comment: no, but it would lower the execution time so that failures would be more apparent and easier to catch.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you could if you run the code via command line or set a [max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

With that said I would highly recommend that you re-architect your code, if your running this code on a Linux box look into [pThreads](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php). The task your trying to do seem like it would be easier with c# if your running on windows machine.

**NOTE** I can't stress enough that if you use threading for this task it will go much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

1. Limit your script to X domains per execution.
2. Create a CRON that runs your script every minute.

This way you won't have to worry too much about memory leaks. You might also want to create a .lock file at the beginning of your process to make sure your CRON doesn't run the script before it's finish. Sometimes when you are requesting information from other websites it might take very long...

Comment: Also, may I suggest you randomize your delays and actions between each request? Servers has logics to detect sequential activities and you could get your IP address ban quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with cron-jobs is that they can end up over-running, and so have more than one copy running at the same time. If you are running multiple copies from Cron at once, there will be a huge load spike, but there might not be anything running for the last 30 seconds of every minute.  (Trust me, I've seen it happen, it was not pretty).

A simple shell script can be set running easily with normal Linux startup mechanisms and will them loop forever. Here, I've added the ability to check for the exit of a PHP script (or whatever) to exit the loop. Add other checks to deliberately slow down execution. Here's [my blogpost](https://phpscaling.com/2009/06/23/doing-the-work-elsewhere-sidebar-running-the-worker/) on the subject.

I would arrange the script to run somewhere from 10-50 domain-scrapes, and then exit, ready to run again until you run out of data to look for, or some other issue happens that requires attention.

```
#!/bin/bash

# a shell script that keeps looping until a specific exit code is given
# Start from /etc/init.d, or SupervisorD, for example. 
# It will restart itself until the script it calls returns a given exit code

nice php -q -f ./cli-worker.php -- $@
ERR=$?

# if php does an `exit(99);` ...
if [ $ERR -eq 99 ]
then
   # planned complete exit
   echo "99: PLANNED_SHUTDOWN";
   exit 0;
fi

sleep 1

# Call ourself, replacing the script without a sub-call
exec $0 $@
```